# Dynamic inner query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there a way to code a dynamic inner query?  Basically, I find myself typing something like the following query over and over:

```
;with tempData as (
   --this inner query is the part that changes, but there's always a timeGMT column.
   select timeGMT, dataCol2, dataCol3
   from tbl1 t1
      join tbl2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
)
select dateadd(ss,d.gmtOffset,t.timeGMT) timeLocal,
   t.*
from tempData t
   join dst d on t.timeGMT between d.sTimeGMT and d.eTimeGMT
where d.zone = 'US-Eastern'
```

The only thing I can think of is a stored proc with the inner query text as the input for some dynamic sql...  However, my understanding of the optimizer (which is, admittedly, limited) says this isn't really a good idea.

Comment: To bad you don't have SQL Server 2008, which supports stored procedures with table-typed parameters.

Comment: How much does the inner query change?  Different assortment of columns from the same joined tables or something completely different?

Comment: @JohnPick, what would the solution look like in SQL Server 2008?  If an update solves all of my problems, I'll update!

Comment: @user92546, The inner query could be any number of things, often related to business logic. The only commonality is that there's a timeGMT column, which needs to be translated to local time for varying DST rules.

Comment: I'm having bad thoughts about using a temporary table (`#Foo`) or table variable (`@Foo`), probably loaded using dynamic SQL.  If that's the answer then you might want to just tack the timezone handling on the end of the initial query and be done with it.  It makes me shiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance perspective, what you have there is the version on which I would expect the optimizer to do the best job.

If the "outer" part of your example is static and code maintenance overrides performance, I'd look to encapsulating the dateadd result in a table-valued function (TVF). Since the time conversion is very much the common thread in these queries, I would definitely focus on that part of the workload.

For example, your query that can vary would look like this:

```
select timeGMT, dataCol2, dataCol3, lt.timeLocal
from   tbl1 t1
       join tbl2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
       cross apply dbo.LocalTimeGet(timeGMT, 'US-Eastern') AS lt
```

Where the TVF dbo.LocalTimeGet contains the logic for dateadd(ss,d.gmtOffset,t.timeGMT) and the lookup of the time zone offset value based on the time zone name. The implementation of that function would look something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LocalTimeGet (
    @TimeGMT  datetime,
    @TimeZone varchar(20)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT  DATEADD(ss, d.gmtOffset, @TimeGMT) AS timeLocal
    FROM    dst AS d
    WHERE   d.zone = @TimeZone
);
GO
```

The upside of this approach is when you upgrade to 2008 or later, there are system functions you could use to make this conversion a lot easier to code and you'll only have to alter the TVF. If your result sets are small, I'd consider a system scalar function (SQL 2008) over a TVF, even if it implements those same system functions. Based on your comment, it sounds like the system functions won't do what you need, but you could still stick with your implementation of a dst table, which is encapsulated in the TVF above.

TVFs can be a performance problem because the optimizer assumes they only return 1 row.

If you need to combine encapsulation and performance, then I'd do the time zone calc in the application code instead. Even though you'd have to apply it to each project that uses it, you would only have to implement it 1x in each project (in the Data Access Layer) and treat it as a common utility library if you'll be using across projects.

Comment: I don't think this handles the problem correctly.  A large part of the "Local Time" correction has to do with Daylight Saving Time, so the join to the dst table is far more interesting than the `dateadd` function.  Am I missing something with what you're describing?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything. I've added the TVF declaration so you can see how your dst implementation is used. Really, you're on the right track, just switch the syntax of "an input query wrapped in a CTE" to "a given query referencing a standard TVF". Unfortunately, the performance caveats do apply. Also, for really tiny result sets, you might find a scalar user-defined function faster than a TVF.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I think you missed part of the where clause in the function though (`and @TimeGMT between d.sTimeGMT and d.eTimeGMT`).  In my quick tests, this wasn't that much of an optimization hit (approx 3-5% increase in CPU time for 10M records).  Another benefit of the TVF is the option to return several columns (i.e. the timezone suffix, like, "-0500 (EST)")

Comment: Yes, I did miss that part of the original code. The BETWEEN test would go in the function's WHERE clause. Yes, they do offer a lot of flexibility. I believe the optimizer gets thrown off when each "input" row to the function has a widely varying # of "output" rows and that # is more than 1. It's not so much the CPU hit. Check the query plan and you'll probably find that you have a lot of seek operations going on where the original version (no function) was possibly using merge joins.

Comment: The other reason you probably aren't seeing much of a drop-off in performance is that in the original, having the BETWEEN test as the join condition makes the engine work quite a lot more compared to an equality test.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's follow-on question, a SQL Server 2008 solution would look like this:

First, create permanent definitions:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.tempDataType AS TABLE (
    timeGMT DATETIME,
    dataCol2 int,
    dataCol3 int)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE ComputeDateWithDST
    @tempData tempDataType READONLY
AS
SELECT dateadd(ss,d.gmtOffset,t.timeGMT) timeLocal, t.*
FROM @tempData t
JOIN dst d ON t.timeGMT BETWEEN d.sTimeGMT AND d.eTimeGMT
WHERE d.zone = 'US-Eastern'
GO
```

Thereafter, whenever you want to plug a subquery (which has now become a separate query, no longer a CTE) into the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @tempData tempDataType

INSERT @tempData
-- sample subquery:
SELECT timeGMT, dataCol2, dataCol3
FROM tbl1 t1
JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID

EXEC ComputeDateWithDST @tempData;
GO
```

Performance could be an issue because you'd be running separately what used to be a CTE instead of letting SQL Server combine it with the main query to optimize the execution plan.